# root.overrideredirect and <Any-KeyPress> binding

Tags: python, events, tkinter, binding

I would like the following program to quit on `<Any-KeyPress>` event.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.overrideredirect(True)
root.bind('<Any-KeyPress>', lambda e: root.destroy())
root.mainloop()
```

This works fine on Windows OS. However this does not work on Ubuntu unless I remove the line `root.overrideredirect(True)` from the above code.

Is this the intended behavior ?

Or is there a way whereby I can make my program to work while still using `root.overrideredirect(True)` ?

**Edit**

---

I just saw a [similar question here at SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20287019/how-to-bind-tkinter-destroy-to-a-key-in-debian), where Bryan Oakley suggests using `root.focus_force()` but it does not help.

**Edit 2**

---

I used `root.attributes('-fullscreen', True)` instead of `root.overrideredirect(True)` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20287877/2348704) and that seems to work now.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to bind Tkinter destroy() to a key in Debian?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20287019/how-to-bind-tkinter-destroy-to-a-key-in-debian)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

root.bind('<Any-KeyPress>', quit())
root.mainloop()
```

Assuming that you want the program to quit, keep the code. If you just want to clear the screen, just use `root.destroy()` rather that `quit()`. Using `root.overrideredirect(True)` will NOT work on Ubuntu.